Which system store and store location do I use?
I hope this question is fitting for Server Fault. It does contain some code, but I don't think it fits Stack Overflow very well.
I have a Python program that saves a self-signed certificate to the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" cache for the "Local Computer". But the problem is that it's not being saved to the correct store (I'm not sure if "store" is the correct terminology).
I see two different paths to what I assumed were the same store, but they are apparently not. Microsoft did a terrific job at making this confusing.

You can see the first path is Local Computer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates. Note: this is opened in the certlm program (Manage computer certificates).
And the second path is Console Root\Certificates (Local Computer)\Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates. Note: This is opened by creating a new Certificates snap-in in MMC and choosing "Computer account".
My program is saving my certificate into the first path, but I need it to go into the second path. That's it. To accomplish this, I think I just need to chose the correct "Store Location". I am using this site as a reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/system-store-locations
My code is pretty simple:
def save_cert_to_store(cert_to_save: str) -> None:
    cert_byte = win32crypt.CryptStringToBinary(
        cert_to_save,
        CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER
    )[0]

    store = win32crypt.CertOpenStore(
        CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
        0,
        None,
        CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE | CERT_STORE_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_FLAG,
        "Root"
    )

    try:
        store.CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore(
            X509_ASN_ENCODING,
            cert_byte,
            CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        store.CertCloseStore(CERT_CLOSE_STORE_FORCE_FLAG)

You can see the system store I am using is CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE and the store location is "Root". When running this, it saves it to Local Computer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates, which I don't want.
If I change "Root" to "Trust", it now saves it to Console Root\Certificates (Local Computer)\Enterprise Trust\Certificates, which is the correct root store, but not the correct path.
Changing "Root" to "CA" saves it to Console Root\Certificates (Local Computer)\Intermediate Certification Authorities\Certificates. Again, correct root store, but wrong path.
So my question is, what is the correct combination of system store/store location to use to save this to the correct path, which is Console Root\Certificates (Local Computer)\Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates? I am running my program as administrator, so I don't believe this is a permissions issue. Unless Microsoft just blocks this entirely without warning.

Are you saying that the two MMC consoles show different certificates? Console Root isn't even part of the certificate system – it's an MMC user interface path...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/system-store-locations

@u1686_grawity - they do appear to be identical

@GregAskew - Yes, that is the same article I linked to in my OP, and the one I have been referencing.


You can see the system store I am using is CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE and the store location is "Root". When running this, it saves it to Local Computer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates, which I don't want.

That is what you want. The "console root" you're concerned about is an artifact of using MMC.exe and has nothing to do with your certificates.

When I save a certificate to this store, Chrome does not pick it up, so I get the certificate unknown warning. That is what I'm trying to avoid. If I save the certificate to Console Root\Certificates (Local Computer)\Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates the browser DOES pick it up, so that is why I assumed I want it saved there. Any idea why the browser isn't picking up the certificate when saved to Local Computer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates?

Correction to my previous comment (can't edit again), if I manually add the certificate to Local Computer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates using the import wizard, the browser does pick it up. If I use my program to add it (it is indeed there in the same spot, I can open it and verify it), the browser does NOT pick it up. Very strange. That would seem to point to my program being the problem, but that doesn't really make sense why I can see the certificate there yet the browser does not see it.

Okay, I guess I didn't test enough, but now it's working fine. The first time I tested it wasn't working, which is when I came here and made this post. Now it is consistently working.
